# Nuxt 3: @sidebase nuxt-auth module - execute callback function after successful login

Tags: nuxt3

I'm using `@sidebase/nuxt-auth` module version `0.6.0-beta.6` for Nuxt 3. Here's how sign in functionality is done:

```
...
const { signIn } = useAuth()
await signIn({ username, password })
if (...) // not executed
```

`signIn` does redirect to a target page right after it has what it needs. How can I execute a function/code after successful login?

Comment: Use `redirect` key inside the `signIn` method as like `await signIn({ username: username.value, password: password.value, redirect: false})`. It will not redirect to target page.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working by providing the `redirect: false` option in the 2nd argument like so: `await signIn({ username, password }, { redirect: false } )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@sidebase/nuxt-auth` provides a key named `redirect` for `useAuth().signIn()`.

We need to add the `redirect` key inside the `signIn()` method. See below code,

```
const { error, url } = await useAuth().signIn('credentials', {
  username: username.value,
  password: password.value,
  redirect: false,
})
```

The answer is solved by adding `redirect` key inside `signIn()` like `await signIn({ username, password }, { redirect: false } )`

For more learn this kind of redirect issue,
[read this.](https://github.com/sidebase/nuxt-auth/issues/493)